# Get all strings between 2 characters

Tags: jquery, regex

I have the following string:

```
"The length must be between <xmin> and <xmax> characters"
```

I'm trying to get all Words/strings that is between `<>` But with my code I only get the following:

```
xmin> and <xmax
```

This is my code:

```js
var srctext = "The length must be between <xmin> and <xmax> characters";
    var re = srctext.match(/\<(.*)\>/).pop();
    console.log(re);
```

How can i get both `xmin` and `xmax` out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) regex to match the least.

```js
var srctext = "The length must be between <xmin> and <xmax> characters";
var re = srctext.match(/<(.*?)>/g);
console.log(re);
```

or use [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

```js
var srctext = "The length must be between <xmin> and <xmax> characters";
var re = srctext.match(/<([^>]*)>/g);
console.log(re);
```

---

**UPDATE :** To get the captured value when regex contains `g`(global) flag use [`RegExp#exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) method with a while loop.

```js
var srctext = "The length must be between <xmin> and <xmax> characters",
    regex=/<([^>]*)>/g,
    m,res=[];

while(m=regex.exec(srctext))
  res.push(m[1])
  
console.log(res);
```